# Lag when using android phone as touchpad

Tags: android

I have made an application that enables to use android phone as touchpad.
It is working correctly as it should. 
But only thing bothering me is that there is LAG. mouse on laptop sometimes lags i.e not in complete sync with touch on android.

The only reason i could think of lag is the logic used in calculating the next coordinates.

Here is the code for Android Application that sends coordinates on touch event :(t is TextView)

```
t.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                startX = event.getX();
                startY = event.getY();
            }

            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
            {

            out.println("X:"+(event.getX()-startX)+"Y:"+(event.getY()-startY));
                startX=event.getX();
                startY=event.getY();
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Logic i am using is that i am sending difference of the coordinates.
On serverside , basic thing happening is ('in' is BufferedReader ):

```
PointerInfo a = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
 Point b = a.getLocation();
 currX = (int)b.getX();
 currY=(int)b.getY();
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
         if(inputLine.equals("LeftClick"))
         {
            robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
            robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);

          }
          else if(inputLine.equals("RightClick")){
            robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK);
           robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK);

          }
          else{
              outputLine = kkp.processInput(inputLine);
    //To break the string into X cordi and Y cordi.
           yloc = inputLine.indexOf("Y");
             float xcord = Float.parseFloat(inputLine.substring(2,yloc));   
                 float ycord = Float.parseFloat(inputLine.substring(yloc+2));

                 robot.mouseMove(currX+Math.round(xcord),currY+Math.round(ycord)); 
                 currX+=Math.round(xcord);
                 currY+=Math.round(ycord);
               }
 }
```

Is the delay normal like Can't be improved . or can be improved by changing the calculations in above code. and PS: i am not using UDP.

Comment: I am using Printwriter to send the coordinates to laptop.
"out" in the application code is object of PrintWriter.